# Remove items from IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have 2 IEnumerable collections.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> objectsToExcept
```

and

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> allObjects.
```

`objectsToExcept` may contain objects from `allObjects`.

I need to remove from `allObjects` objects in `objectsToExcept`. For example:

```
foreach (var myClass in objectsToExcept)
{
allObjects.Remove(myClass);
}
```

Or

```
allObject.Except(objectsToExcept)
```

But it doesn't work. The count after the methods have execute indicate that no items have been removed.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I don't see how the first version would compile, and the second version won't do anything unless you use the result. It doesn't remove anything from the existing collection - indeed, there may not even *be* an in-memory collection backing it. It just returns a sequence which, when iterated over, will return the appropriate values.

If you *are* using the result, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> others = allObjects.Except(objectsToExcept);
foreach (MyClass x in others)
{
    ...
}
```

then it should be fine *if* you've overridden `GetHashCode` and `Equals` *or* if you're happy to use reference equality. Are you trying to remove logically-equal values, or do the same *references* occur in both sequences? Have you overridden `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, and if so, are you sure those implementations work?

Basically it should be fine - I suggest you try to create a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem; I suspect that while doing so, you'll find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 30):

There is no `Remove` method on `IEnumerable<T>`, because it is not meant to be modifiable.

The `Except` method doesn't modify the original collection: it returns a new collection that doesn't contain the excluded items:

```
var notExcluded = allObjects.Except(objectsToExcept);
```

See `Except` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779.aspx).

Comment: `Remove` exists as an extension method in the Linq to XML space, but doesn't do what the OP is trying to do. Oddly enough you see it on the documentation page for the members of `IEnumerable<T>` but it has a restriction `where T : XNode`. Technically `Except` isn't on `IEnumerable<T>` either, but that is being absolutely too picky.

Comment: @Mike Two, indeed, I never noticed that... it looks like a bug in the documentation

Answer (score 17):

Remove and Except do not modify the original IEnumerable. They return a new one. try

```
var result = allObject.Except(objectsToexcept);
```

Answer (score 5):

While the other answers are correct, I have to add that the result of the `Except()` call can be assigned back to the original variable. That is,

```
allObjects = allObjects.Except(objectsToExcept);
```

Also keep in mind that `Except()` will produce the set difference of the two collections, so if there are duplicates of the variables to be removed, they will all be removed.

Comment: Only if the source is not typed to something.  List.Except cannot be assigned back to List without be enumerated.