# How to remove items in IEnumerable<MyClass>?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

How do I remove items from a IEnumerable that match specific criteria?

RemoveAll() does not apply.

Comment: Do you have a class definition and the criteria?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185975/remove-items-from-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't; `IEnumerable` as an interface does not support removal.

If your `IEnumerable` instance is actually of a type that supports removal (such as `List<T>`) then you can cast to that type and use the `Remove` method.

Alternatively you can copy items to a different `IEnumerable` based on your criteria, or you can use a lazy-evaluated query (such as with Linq's `.Where`) to filter your `IEnumerable` on the fly. Neither of these will affect your original container, though.

Comment: In my case, the code was executing `.Aggregate` on the `IEnumerable`.  I inserted a `.Where` filter as Dan suggested, eg. `foo.Where(condition).Aggregate(expression)`.  It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

This will produce a new collection rather than modifying the existing one however I think it is the idiomatic way to do it with LINQ.

```
    var filtered = myCollection.Where(x => x.SomeProp != SomValue);
```

Another option would be to use `Where` to produce a new `IEnumerable<T>` with references to the objects you want removed then pass that to a `Remove` call on the original collection. Of course that would actually consume more resources.

Comment: What is _this_ in _This will produce a new collection_?

Comment: @AustinSalonen using `Where` will produce a new collection. LINQ queries generally do not modify the existing collection, instead they produce a new `IEnumerable<T>` with the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove items from an `IEnumerable<T>`. You can remove items from an `ICollection<T>` or filter items from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
// filtering example; does not modify oldEnumerable itself
var filteredEnumerable = oldEnumerable.Where(...);
// removing example
var coll = (ICollection<MyClass>)oldEnumerable;
coll.Remove(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't *remove* items from an `IEnumerable`.  It's not possible.  It's just a sequence of items.  You can remove items from some underlying source that generates the sequences, for example if the `IEnumerable` is based on a list you can remove items from that list.

The other option you have is to create a new sequence, based on this one, that never shows the given items.  You can do that using `Where`, but it's important to realize this isn't removing items, but rather choosing to show items based on a certain condition.

Comment: It's not impossible. @TimS. alluded to it in his answer. Also see my answer on another question about a similar topic at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15858794/425871

Comment: @Steve As I *stated* in my answer, you can remove items from some collection that is the underlying data source for an `IEnumerable`.  That's still not removing items from an `IEnumerable` though, that's removing items from the underlying data source.

Comment: Your right - I didn't read your answer quite closely enough :)

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has already stated, you can't remove from `IEnumerable` because that is not what the interface is describing.

Consider the following example:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetSomeStrings()
{
    yield return "FirstString";
    yield return "Another string";
}
```

Clearly, removing an element from this `IEnumerable` is not something you can reasonably do, instead you'd have to make a new enumeration without the ones you don't want.

The `yield` keyword provides other examples, for example, you can have infinite lists:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetPowersOf2()
{
    int value = 1;

    while(true)
    {
        yield return value;
        value = value * 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Items cannot be removed from an `IEnumerable<T>`. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it and use the `List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)` this is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do,

```
IEnumerable<T> myVar=getSomeData(); // Assume mayVar holds some data

myVar=myVar.Where(d=>d.Id>10); // thats all, i want data with Id>10 only
```

Answer (score -1):

How about trying `Enumerable.Empty` i.e.

```
T obj = new T();
IEnumerable<T> myVar = new T[]{obj}    //Now myVar has an element
myVar = Enumerable.Empty<T>();        //Now myVar is empty
```

Comment: Assigning a new value to the variable won't affect the original value.